# AngularJS set check box checked default with checklist-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I've check boxes inside the `ng-repeat` loop and I'm using `checklist-model` to get the checked value.  However I need to set those check boxes checked in by default.
I've used `ng-checked="true"`.  however it shows check box is checked but value is empty when submit it.
code is:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="line_items in orderItems">
<td align="center" data-ng-if="line_items.id">
    <div class="vd_checkbox checkbox-success">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{$index}}"
              checklist-model="comp.orderItemSelect"
              checklist-value="line_items.id"  ng-checked="true"/>
          <label for="checkbox-{{$index}}">&nbsp;</label>
     </div>
</td>
<tr>
```

ng-checked show check box is checked but `checklist-model` not get it as selected. How do I default checked checkbox with `checklist-model` ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ng-checked

my example

```
<div ng-repeat="weekDay in weekDays">
    <input 
        checklist-value="weekDay.id" 
        checklist-model="scheduleData.sch_day"
        type="checkbox">
        {{ weekDay.name }}
</div>
```

my controller

```
$scope.weekDays = [ { 'name': 'Mon', 'id': '1' }, 
                    { 'name': 'Tue', 'id': '2' }, 
                    { 'name': 'Wed', 'id': '3' },
                    { 'name': 'Thu', 'id': '4' }, 
                    { 'name': 'Fri', 'id': '5' }, 
                    { 'name': 'Sat', 'id': '6' },
                    { 'name': 'Sun', 'id': '7' },                           
                ];
$scope.scheduleData = {sch_day:['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']};
```

This will work